# php parse_ini_file set keys as strings

Tags: php, arrays, ini

I'm running into an error with the `parse_ini_file` function.

Here's the section of the file that's causing problems:

```
TYPE["A"]          = 1  
TYPE["B"]          = 2  
TYPE["C"]          = 3
```

This parses fine in PHP 5.3.1-- but it throws a `PHP Warning:  Error parsing` in PHP 5.2.17

Is it possible to set a string as the array key in an ini file in PHP 5.2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the second parameter of `parse_ini_file` to true to get multidimensional array.

Your ini file:

```
[type]
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
```

You PHP:

```
$arr = parse_ini_file('my_ini_file', true);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
            [A] => 1
            [B] => 2
            [C] => 3
        )

)
```